# Applying generics to generics

Tags: typescript

Given generic type `Fn` below, which takes another generic as input (`Idiot`).  Is there a way to subsequently apply generics to that generic (`A_` being applied to `Idiot`) to then determine the right types?

```js
type Fn = <Idiot extends <A>(a:A)=>A>(
  inputFn: (i:any)=>Idiot
)=><A_>(a: Parameters<Idiot<A_>>)=>ReturnType<Idiot<A_>>
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=57&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAPASQCYEsD2woQAewEcGAzqgIIB8AFAIYBcVAlIjbXQFBRRZwwAV2DwmUOliYM4IdjUy5g3eSioB9esygAFBgCcGAWwgl95dNjxrNNeQCVTQ-XAAq4CJaU2aNbv6A)

Comment: @jcalz - that's the official name of that combinator in Combinatorial Logic.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Birds.html

Comment: Ah, looked it up.  That's not it's "official name" so much as a name given to the I combinator in Raymond Smullyan's [To Mock A Mockingbird](https://www.amazon.com/Mock-Mockingbird-Raymond-Smullyan/dp/0192801422).  I think "Identity" is likely to be more commonplace than "Idiot".